# KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /

Tags: apache-pulsar

I'm trying to initialize metadata with pulsar 2.9.1 and zookeeper 3.6.3 and I'm getting the following error

````
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pulsar.metadata.api.MetadataStoreException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.ZKMetadataStore.<init>(ZKMetadataStore.java:89)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.MetadataStoreFactoryImpl.newInstance(MetadataStoreFactoryImpl.java:52)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.MetadataStoreFactoryImpl.createExtended(MetadataStoreFactoryImpl.java:36)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.api.extended.MetadataStoreExtended.create(MetadataStoreExtended.java:43)
    at org.apache.pulsar.PulsarClusterMetadataSetup.initMetadataStore(PulsarClusterMetadataSetup.java:338)
    at org.apache.pulsar.PulsarClusterMetadataSetup.main(PulsarClusterMetadataSetup.java:203)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:106)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.addWatch(ZooKeeper.java:3192)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.PulsarZooKeeperClient.access$3301(PulsarZooKeeperClient.java:74)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.PulsarZooKeeperClient$23.call(PulsarZooKeeperClient.java:1130)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.PulsarZooKeeperClient$23.call(PulsarZooKeeperClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.PulsarZooKeeperClient$ZooWorker.syncCallWithRetries(PulsarZooKeeperClient.java:1529)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.PulsarZooKeeperClient.addWatch(PulsarZooKeeperClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.pulsar.metadata.impl.ZKMetadataStore.<init>(ZKMetadataStore.java:82)
    ... 5 more```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.